# How to apply pandas.DataFrame.replace on selected columns with inplace = True?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':[99,99,99],
    'col2':[4,5,6],
    'col3':[7,None,9]
})

col_list = ['col1','col2']
df[col_list].replace(99,0,inplace=True)
```

This generates a Warning and leaves the dataframe unchanged.

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

I want to be able to apply the replace method on a subset of the columns specified by the user. I also want to use inplace = True to avoid making a copy of the dataframe, since it is huge. Any ideas on how this can be accomplished would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to work if you loop and replace one column at a time, though there must be a better alternative?

Comment: Yes, but I have 2k columns so I was hoping for a faster approach. Also, I have the same problem with the dropna function. That one cannot be applied to one column at at time because I want to use the 'thresh' argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select the columns for replacement with `df[col_list]`, a slice (a copy) of your dataframe is created. The copy is updated, but never written back into the original dataframe.

You should either replace one column at a time or use nested dictionary mapping:

```
df.replace(to_replace={'col1' : {99 : 0}, 'col2' : {99 : 0}}, 
           inplace=True)
```

The nested dictionary for `to_replace` can be generated automatically:

```
d = {col : {99:0} for col in col_list}
```

Comment: You cannot drop cells from individual columns. Only the whole row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace with loc. Here is a slightly modified version of your sample df:

```
d = {'col1':[99,99,9],'col2':[99,5,6],'col3':[7,None,99]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
col_list = ['col1','col2']
df.loc[:, col_list] = df.loc[:, col_list].replace(99,0)
```

You get

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   0       0       7.0
1   0       5       NaN
2   9       6       99.0
```

[Here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11984) is a nice explanation for similar issue.

Comment: Yes, I agree that using loc you can reassign sub-dataframes +1. However, a comment: `df[col_list].replace(99,0)` is sufficient on right side and has in my experience been quicker.